# Linq: Find Element in a Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a collection called `Albums` with objects from the class `Album`. This class has a property `Songs`, which is a collection of `Song` objects. Each `Song` has an unique Id.

```
public IQueryable<Album> Albums

public class Album
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Song> Songs { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Song
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**Is it possible, using Linq, to find a Song in the Album collection?** I have no idea how, I am new to Linq.
I tried a bit:

```
Albums.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Songs.Id == id);
```

Thanks a lot,

Vincent

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Albums.SelectMany(a=>a.Songs).FirstOrDefault(song => song.Id == id)
```

The SelectMany will create a flattened list of all songs for all albums allowing you to then select the first with the appropriate id.

Answer (score 6):

You need to do this if you have an album...

```
var album = GetAlbum();
var song = album.Songs.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);
```

Or this if you don't...

```
var song = albumsCollection.SelectMany(s => s.Songs).FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to return the album that contains the song with a given Id, you should use the following query:

```
Albums.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Songs.Any(s => s.Id == Id));
```

if you want to get the song:

```
Albums.SelectMany(a=>a.Songs).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == Id);
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to find an ablum with a certain song:

```
Album albumFound = Albums.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Songs.FirstOrDefault(song => song.Id == id) != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from album in Albums
            from song in album.Songs
            where song.Id == id;

var song = query.FirstOrDefault();
```