# Searching a WPF list box in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a register that gets data for a person when you click on their name in a list box, it works great, but the person I am making it for has requested to be able to search the list box. I have looked all over the internet and haven't been able to find any simple help on this topic, I am fairly new to c# so a simple solution would be much appreciated

Comment: there are a lot of examples if you search for *wpf search listbox* with your favorite search engine

Answer (score 0):

In essence, for what you need to do, there are two operations you need to know how to perform, which are kind of independent from one another:

1. Getting a collection from a `ListBox` in WPF
2. Finding an item on a collection

## How to get a collection from a ListBox

A `ListBox` holds its items on a collection. We just need to access that collection and then query it to find the item we want. Depending on how you're defining the items of your `ListBox`, you can get the collection containing its items by using its `Items` or `ItemsSource` property. The type of the items on the `ListBox` depends totally on how you populated the `ListBox`. WPF data templating conventions and patterns assume you are populating the `ListBox` with a data type (like your `MyCoolObject`), so operations like this one you're trying to accomplish are easy to perform.

See [ItemsControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) class documentation for more information. `ListBox` is an `ItemsControl` derived class and this documentation describes how controls with items are used in WPF.

## How to find an item on a collection

It all depends on where you're storing your items, but assuming you're storing your items on some collection, you can use LINQ to find an item.

For example, you might be using an hypothetical custom object, named `MyCoolObject`, which has a `String` property named `Text`, which would look like the following:

```
public class MyCoolObject
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Now, suppose you have a collection somewhere like the following:

```
public List<MyCoolObject> myCollection;
```

You can search an item inside your collection using a LINQ query like this one:

```
var foundObjects = myCollection.Where((myObject) => myObject.Text.Equals("Text you want to find", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

The `Where` method I use above, accepts a delegate, which I provide as a lambda expression for convenience. In this example, I search for objects whose `Text` property equals to "Text you want to find", using binary comparison and ignoring case. The `Where` method, then returns a collection containing all the found objects, which is stored on the `foundObjects` variable.

The `Where` method, gets all items on the collection that match that text, but you could simply use the `FirstOrDefault` method, which would return only the first object on the collection.

As a side note, remember LINQ features require you to insert the following using directive on the top of your C# file for them to be available:

```
using System.Linq;
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062954/linq-find-element-in-a-collection) for more information on how to find an item on a collection with C#. This has several simple answers that explain many ways to find what you need on a collection.
See also [List.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.7.2) method documentation, which describes how to use the `Find` method of a `List` collection, in case you're using a `List` as your collection. This one is not a LINQ feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a textbox to hold the search element, loop through the listbox items searching for the element while keeping track of the listbox index. Set the ListBox selectedIndex to the relevant index when found.

If Linq is too complicated, just use a for or foreach loop